# C/C++ languge, automatic parsing configuration file of struct variable members

Tags: c++, c, struct

I am looking for an automatic method to parsing a configuration file which store many stuct variable member values.

For example, we have a struct variable named as following:

```
struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
}struct_example
```

Then we have a configuration file stored this struct variable values:

```
struct_example:
    a: 5
    b: 10
```

And a simple way to set struct values would be like:

```
struct_example example;
// supporse we have read string of "5" and "10" from configuration file and store
// it to string variable string_a, string_b;
example.a = atoi(string_a);
example.b = atoi(string_b);
```

However, if we have 100 struct members, we have to write 100 lines code to set value; If we have 1000 struct members, we have to write even 1000 lines code for configuration.

Do we more automatic method for such struct member configuration? Such as a function:

```
void struct_member_config(string member_name, string member_value, struct_example* struct_variable);
```

Comment: there are no C/C++ language. They're very different languages and structs are also very different in them. Choose only one

Comment: Never used it, but 'Json' may fulfill your need. It's not as compact as your example, but I gather that this is its purpose... Check the Wikipedia page...

Comment: I wouldn't wish YAML on my worst enemy, but it might be an option.

Comment: So write something to parse your config files, and bobs your uncle.

Comment: No need for 100 or 1000 lines of code. For example, in C++ you would write an [`operator>>` overload](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4421706/4581301) and call it in a loop. In C you would replace the overload with a plain old function and do the same thing.

Comment: Neither C nor C++ has introspection capabilities powerful enough to do this automatically.  You'd need to either write a program to parse your C++ header and generate the necessary C++ code to read in a config file and set values in the struct, or find a program that does that.  Google's Protocol Buffers package comes to mind, although it's more oriented towards binary serialization that human-readable config files.  It might have an ASCII text mode though, I don't know.

Comment: The files wouldn't be human readable/editable; though, have you considered writing and reading structures to a file in their native memory layout?  For example, `write(fd,&struct_example,sizeof(struct_example))` and later `read(fd,&struct_example,sizeof(struct_example))`!?  This could easily be extended for looped writes and reads.  For portability, make sure you're considering platform-specific alignment differences.

Comment: Hi, it looks like I have no choice except work around. Well, maybe 'Json' would be the best choices. Regard struct variable layout, it would be not covinient for mannul settings.